# Servo Speed Changer with Buttons

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, servo, button, debounce

ok so yesterday i was in trouble with the buttons, with help from you i got over it and everything worked fine with the 1st speed of the servo, then i added the other 2 speeds and it looks like it all messed up... the buttons don`t respond as they should and the servo moves very weirdly. 
Here is the code:

```
const int button1Pin = 2;
const int button2Pin = 3;
const int ledPin1 = 13;
const int ledPin2 = 12;
const int ledPin3 = 11;
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo1;


int x = 0;
int button1State = 0;
int lastButton1State = 0;
int button2State = 0;
int lastButton2State = 0;



void setup() {
  servo1.attach(9);
  pinMode(button1Pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2Pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    int position;
    button1State = digitalRead(button1Pin);
    button2State = digitalRead(button2Pin);

      if (button1State != lastButton1State)
     {
        if (button1State == HIGH) 
          {
            x++;
            Serial.println("on1");
            Serial.print("number of button Pushes:  ");
            Serial.println(x);
          }
        else 
          {
            Serial.println("off1");  
          }
     }

    if (button2State != lastButton2State)
      {    
        if (button2State == HIGH) 
          {
            x--;
            Serial.println("on2");
            Serial.print("number of button Pushes:  ");
            Serial.println(x);
          }
        else 
          {
            Serial.println("off2"); 
          }
       }
          delay(1000);

lastButton1State = button1State;
lastButton2State = button2State;

  if(x == 1)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);
        for(position = 0; position < 360; position += 2)
          {
            servo1.write(position);
            delay(20);
          }
    }
   else if (x == 2)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);
        for(position = 0; position <360; position += 5)
          {
            servo1.write(position);
            delay(20);
          }
    }
   else 
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);
        for(position = 0; position < 360; position += 10)
          {
            servo1.write(position);
            delay(20);
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be better ways to mitigate button bounce. Check [this link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce) for a discussion on button bounce and example code to work around this problem. In your code, it appears you can not press your buttons faster than once a second.

Determine if the servos you are using are capable of the range you are demanding.  Some servos only travel from 0 degrees to 180 degrees.  Your code is asking the servo to travel from 0 degrees to 360 degrees.  Also, it is unlikely that any normal servo can travel this far.  Most servos use a potentiometer as a feed back sensor.  And most potentiometers can only be turned to something less than 1 full revolution.

It is likely you have not given the servos enough time to move to the zero degree position at the start of each of your 3 loops.  Understand that normal servos can not make complete revolutions.  They need to stay within their designed limit of rotation.  If you want to start over at 0 degrees you need to allow the servos time to rotate back in reverse to the 0 degree position.

Consider your last loop.  You are asking the servo to move from 0 degrees to 360 degrees in 10 degree steps.  You are allowing 20ms per step.  That means the servo will be demanded to move almost a complete revolution in (((360 / 10) * 0.020 = 0.72 seconds) less than a second.  Some but not all servos can move that fast.

Comment: so i should add more delay? another way to button bounce i don`t really know... can you tell me more?

Comment: If the code restricts you pressing the button no faster than once a second and you are fine with that, you can leave that part for later.  (Unless there is another problem with that bit of the code.) However you need to tell the servos to go to zero degrees & give the servos some time to do this before each of the 3 loops.  Finally, you need to determine how fast the servo can actually respond.  I might try increasing the 20ms delay for all loops equally until I noticed a speed difference for the 2 fastest loops.

Comment: that is actually a good idea, i just got home and i`m gonna try this out and tell you how it worked out

Comment: ok so trying this out still not a solution, i tried removing the servo part of the code and it looks just fine, the buttons work perfectly and the leds light up corespondingly. I think that the problem stands in making the servo rotate endesly. At the start x = 0 so nothing happens, i press the button once so it adds 1 to x, x = 1. After the x = 1 the code enters a loop from which it can`t get out, it must move the servo continously so it doesn`t allow any other functions to work out, like the buttons. Just an idea i don`t know if this is true.

Comment: The stack exchange format is not well suited for code debugging.  Unless there is a specific question about the code, it is difficult to adhere to the 1 specific question and 1 concise answer format.  That said, there may be problems with you code.  For instance, I would be annoyed that nothing happens after pressing a button for at least a second.  Second, you never control your "x" counter. It could get very large or it could also go negative.  And who knows what may happen if you told the servo library method to set the servo to a negative angle. Did you at least try to add the new delays?

Comment: i know it's not the best for that but it's my only solution. I don't know any other forum where i could find people that could help and i don't know irl people with programming experience. I'm willing to help and work a lot but i sometimes need some help :) I did everything that you said, adding the delays, lowering the servos speed and giving them time to go to 0 degrees. Although i think it would be pointless to tell the servo to go everytime to 0 when i actually want it to make it spin continously how it does for a fan for example. Thanks for taking your time and helping me man!

Comment: and for the X counter, this would be permanently controled by a human so i didn't want to make the code more complicate by adding some limits to x

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem.  A normal servo can not rotate more than once!  There is a POT or potentiometer inside the servo and, as the volume control in an old amplifier, can only be rotated about 300 (maybe 330) degrees.  There is something called a Continuous Servo.  Instead of position, you control the forward and reverse speed.  That is to say, you will know how fast a Continuous Servo is rotating but you will not know its position at any given moment. For your code to work, you need to start thinking about moving your servo like the wipers move on your car's windscreen or windshield.

Comment: You should also be aware that some servos will not rotate more than 180 degrees.  If you have such servos they may act unexpectedly if asked to go beyond their physical limits.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I think i need to go get a Continuous Servo as you said. I hope i find one soon and buy it. When i do so i will redo the code and update you on the situation. And yes i think my servos go only to 180, i just tried a simple code to make it to 270 and it didn't work that far. Thank you very much for talking your time and helping me kind sir! Have a great day and I`ll update you if it works with the other Servo. (also sorry for my bad English, not my 1st language)

Comment: Just to be clear, normal servos are used to position things.  Like steering a robot.  Continuous servos are used to propel things.  Like pushing a robot.

Comment: yeah yeah I got the idea, this servo came in the box with the arduino as a starter pack. I thought I couldn't control a normal motor so I chose this one instead. Never thought i couldn't actually fully rotate it at different speeds and could only do it until a certain point. Thanks for clearing that out for me! :D